# What does this phrase mean: "for a dominion superior to any visible bond kept him tied to the trunk of the chestnut tree"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

An excerpt from [One Hundred years of Solitude:](http://www.100niangudu.com/en-31_2.html)

> He stayed there, exposed to the sun and the rain, as if the thongs were unnecessary, **for a dominion superior to any visible bond kept him tied to the trunk of the chestnut tree.**

I don't understand the whole sentence in bold.
My analysis of this sentence is that since what is before and after "for" can be viewed as a complete sentence, "for" is a conjunction here, meaning "used to introduce the reason for sth mentioned in the previous statement."  I can't, however, extract any cause-effect relations from the sentence.

Another thing is the comprehension of the sentence "a dominion superior to any visible bond kept him tied to the trunk of the chestnut tree." Specifically, the meaning of the subject "a dominion superior to any visible bond" eludes me, despite understanding the meaning of every word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seem to be "thongs" (physical bonds) tying him to a chestnut tree, but something beyond that (a dominion superior to any physical bond) kept him there. The thongs were not necessary.
In this sentence, "dominion" has this sense:
[American Heritage Dictionary "dominion"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=dominion)

> 2. A territory or sphere of influence or control; a realm.

It means to say that something spiritual, such as affection or obligation, kept him there at that tree, despite the pain of exposure to sun and rain.

The word "for" is equivalent here to "because":
He stayed at the tree exposed to sun and rain *because* something spiritual obligated him to stay.

FWIW, the book is an English translation of "Cien años de soledad" (Gabriel García Marquez), and the passage is the translation of this Spanish sentence:

> Siguió expuesto al sol y la lluvia, como si las sogas
> fueran innecesarias, porque un dominio superior a cualquier atadura visible lo mantenía amarrado
> al tronco del castaño.